# Return a literal string of a tuple in python

Tags: python, string

Let's suppose I have a tuple

```
tup = (14, 180, 255)
```

I would like to return a string of this tuple, literally as it is, not just the values inside.

```
str_tup = magic_function(tup)
str_tup 
> '(14, 180, 255)'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

`str(tup)`

Read the Python docs, please.